Why does my bluetooth keep cutting out?
Whenever I'd connect my headphones to my bluetooth, it cuts out at random points without disconnecting. This doesn't happen on my phone, and didn't happen when I used windows. It also happens with my controller where inputs won't register for a few seconds before working again. I looked over the internet and didn't find anyone else having this problem.
